# How to retrieve data from nested json volley/android

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, jsonparser

I want to get all titles from this JSON. I am using the Volley library.

JSON source: https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1AtYF5g2_A3AiAhejVj595bDLxO1zoGq7PNGjbdV9U8Q?fields=sheets.properties.title&key=AIzaSyDLeY5OUn8KKHeBY6PSZJbBE8rIIME_9dc

**My Code:**

```
public void getAllName(){
    String urls = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1AtYF5g2_A3AiAhejVj595bDLxO1zoGq7PNGjbdV9U8Q?fields=sheets.properties.title&key=AIzaSyDLeY5OUn8KKHeBY6PSZJbBE8rIIME_9dc";

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urls,
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject feedObj = response.getJSONObject("sheets");
                JSONArray entryArray = feedObj.getJSONArray("properties");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Please tell me how to get all the titles...
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sheets");

List<String> titles = IntStream.range(0,jsonArray.length())
        .mapToObj(i -> jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                .getJSONObject("properties")
                .getString("title"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

```
[CSE522, EEE, BBA, MBA, SWE555, CSE625, CSE721, CSE250, CSE775, CSE499]
```

Comment: I am glad I could help :)

Comment: You can try to solve this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244846/how-to-get-data-from-google-sheet-api-v4-json-in-android-volley" @BuildSlayer

Answer (score 0):

Ref:https://stackoverflow.com/a/49839058/13533028

From your Json Response, your title data is inside properties which are inside sheets.
JsonObject can be retrieved from Json  using getJsonObject("name of the property")

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sheets");

    JSONArray  properties= dataArray.getJsonObject(YOUR_ELEMENT_NO);
```

now you can use properties.title in the same way and use it as you like.

Also, I would suggest using Retrofit for networking tasks since it makes networking tasks much easier.